# Mail is not sent to specific domain

Tags: php, email-server, sendmail

We are using php mail function to send emails to our customers. Few days ago, we've found that email are not delivered to only *hotmail.com* domain. I've checked email log to see if there are any error messages, and here is what I've found:

```
Aug 30 23:02:50 XXX sendmail[35378]: AXXX: to=<XX@hotmail.com>, ctladdr=<apache@XXX> (48/48), delay=00:00:05, xdelay=00:00:05, mailer=esmtp, pri=121148, relay=mx.XXX. [], dsn=5.6.0, stat=Data format error

Aug 30 23:02:50  sendmail[35378]: DSN: Data format error
```

What is this ***Data format error*** and how it can be fixed? What is this ctladdr and do I need to set it using PHP or not? Do I need to contact my server provider about this issue, or this is my php application related issue?

My PHP code for sending the emails is:

```
       function send_email( $name_from, $email_from, $email_to, $subject, $message, $headers="" ) {

    $returnVal = 0;

    // made it through validation, send email
    $subject = trim( $subject );
    $message = trim( $message );
    $headers .= "FROM: $name_from <$email_from>";

    if( mail( "$email_to", "$subject", "$message", "$headers") or die ( trigger_error ( "Error: ", E_USER_ERROR ))) {
        $returnVal = 1;
    }
    return $returnVal;
}
```

As you can see in my `$headers` I set the FROM field.

Thx for answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The domain name of your server is not being accepted (used in the FROM). It either is not resolvable, has incorrect format, etc.

Comment: The domain name of your server is not being accepted - Accepted by who? Please can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: It looks like the local sendmail is not accepting it. The weird part is that you mention it only fails for hotmail.com. It should fail for everybody. In any case, having a proper From field (user@domain.tld, resolvable) is the best practice. You probably should fix it in the PHP script if you don't have control over the sendmail configuration (to apply a default domain, for instance).

Comment: I update my question, and added PHP code I use for sending the emails. As you can see i set the FROM field!

Comment: Where is the value of $email_from coming from? What is it when the operation fails?

Comment: The $email_from is passed as function argument. The value is info@mydomain.com.

Comment: Is it always info@mydomain.com? Can it vary? Can you add debugging code so it's printed out and you can compare when it fails?

Comment: It is always info@mydomain.com. It is hardcoded. When I receive email to my Gmail, I can se that FROM field is set to info@mydomain.com.

Comment: Checking the source code there are only two situations that would generate a dsn=5.6.0 code. Look for these messages in /var/log/maillog:  "header overflow from %s during message collect"  or "headers too large (%d max) from %s during message collect" (account for %s/%d that won't be in the log message).

Comment: I checked 4 mail log files, but none of them are containing specified messages :(

Comment: Omigod, things are getting more difficult :) Try increase the LogLevel in /etc/mail/sendmail.cf and send email to hotmail.com again.

Comment: I have no privileges to edit sendmail.cf :(. Maybe I should contact my server provider? Last time they told be something you did, that my from field is not set, but it is as you can see.

Comment: I think that's a good idea. I'm totally out of ideas now.. root access would be needed.

Comment: I'd also suggest a manual SMTP test (for example with the `telnet` command).  That way you can confirm that sendmail is happy (or not so happy) with the sender/recipient you want.